# Disable highlighting around braces in sublime text 2

Tags: macos, sublime-text-2

How to avoid the dark color highlighting around matched braces in sublimetext 2.     [image]

I tried setting few options in Preference -> Default (and user) settings.

```
"matchBrackets" : false,
"matchBracketsSquare": false,
"matchBracketsBraces": false,
"autoMatchEnabled": false,
"autoMatchEnabled": false
```

Comment: You set `"match_brackets_content": false,` right? And you did not forget the "comma" after the last line you listed (unless it is the last line in your preferences file)?

Comment: thanks. I didn't, but even after setting it to false, the problem remains.  The above lines were last in the pref. btw, I saw above settings somewhere in the docs, and surprised no underscore as you suggested. But, I searched for everything "match" in that config file and set to false. still, no effect.

Comment: Odd. I only see the underlined brackets on Windows (which you can turn off using "match_brackets": false). Whereabouts is your cursor in your screnshot? It looks like you've selected the quotes...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds it could be a plugin issue. I assume you checked if BracketHighlighter was installed.

https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter